# Is rest service connection (or whatever) closed after 20 seconds?

Tags: android, resttemplate

I have a problem when use spring restful with android.

My code like that.

1. Activity

```
public class TestRestTemplate extends Activity {
    final static String TAG = "TestRestTemplate";

    TextView tvResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_rest_template);

        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        new MyTask().execute("test");
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // The URL for making the POST request
            String url = CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL + "/testRestTemplate";

            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

            // Sending a JSON or XML object i.e. "application/json" or
            // "application/xml"
            requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            // Populate the Message object to serialize and headers in an
            // HttpEntity object to use for the request
            String returnObj = null;
            try {
                HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(
                        params[0], requestHeaders);

                // Create a new RestTemplate instance
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);

                // Make the network request, posting the message, expecting
                // a String in response from the server
                returnObj = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity,
                        String.class);
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("resttemplate errors");
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG + "-Exception", "" + e.getMessage());
            }
            return returnObj;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tvResult.append("\n" + result);
        }
    }   
}
```

2. And the test_rest_template.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Request Server" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result::" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3. In server side

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HomeController.class);

    int count = 0;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testRestTemplate", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getDataFromClient(@RequestBody String clientData) {

        logger.info("request " + (++count) + " times");

        return count + " times request and return client data = " + clientData;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the first time when I click on the button, it connect to server and response a string successfully, but after that, if I wait for 21 seconds or greater, then click on the button, i got an exception occurred in logcat.

```
12-12 13:56:30.246: W/dalvikvm(1796): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: resttemplate errors
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at vn.com.bip.personal_schedule.activity.TestRestTemplate$MyTask.doInBackground(TestRestTemplate.java:68)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at vn.com.bip.personal_schedule.activity.TestRestTemplate$MyTask.doInBackground(TestRestTemplate.java:1)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-12 13:56:30.266: E/AndroidRuntime(1796):     ... 5 more
```

I googling for this pattern about 2 days but not found any helpful suggestion. Anyone of you can explain to me this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a rest request, use a HttpURLConnection and log the result as a string. It will allow you to follow what's happening. You seem to have a parsing related error.

Did you consider using [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) to perform your rest requests ? It's better than an AsyncTask.

Comment: I tried to use RoboSpice and relized that this is a good solution to perform the rest request. Thankyou for your advice. But I still say that, my problem has not been resolved yet. 
But one point I relized is when I test my code in avd 4.0 or greater, the error occurred, but for avd 2.3 or belower it works fine. I'm really confused with this.

Comment: And Another point is that if I use POST method, the problem happened, but if I use GET method, it work fine....

Comment: Try to use Google REST client. It is a plugin for Chrome that let you query a webserver. You will know if the problem is on the server side or on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It may not a fully answer, but I found the way to resolve above problem.

RestTemplate use `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` for Android 2.3 (GINGERBREAD) or greater and `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` for Android version below 2.3 so if I force RestTemplate must use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` as this code

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true, requestFactory);
```

the problem has resolved.

I'm not enough of time to find out why the problem happened, so if any Expert of you known about that, please share for us

Thanks in advance.